# In Android how to add text over image at specific position

Tags: android, android-layout

in this link: 
http://mynameart.com/create-card/lovely-couple-made-for-each-other
His Name Here  and Her Name Here TextView are there. So i want a same UI that work on all devices.
So how can i achieve the same UI in Android?

Comment: yes you can achieve

Comment: i have tried with fix textView over imageView, but on different resolution devices, textview overlap on image.

Comment: yes,but i have tried with weights as well, its not working.So is there any way to achieve same as above link.

Comment: put your code which you have tried. it will be better for everyone to understand and help.

Comment: Sure i will share that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="His Name Here"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Her Name Here"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="lovely couple made for eachother"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </TableRow>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: for `@dimen/left_margin`, you need to take dimension for different size.